# reduce spacing between ListView Items in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have this list in xamarin portable app and i cant seem to be able to remove or at least reduce spacing between items ,and disable item selection also .

```
<ListView x:Name="ListGroups" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Stash.Groups}}" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
      <ViewCell>
             <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Aqua" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

then some labels

```
 <Label Text="If you feel you're missing"
            FontSize="15"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            TextColor="White"
            />
     <Label Text="a group or two, please contact"
               FontSize="15"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            TextColor="White"
            />
     <Label Text="your manager"
             FontSize="15"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            TextColor="White"
            />


     </StackLayout>
```

[ImageBackgroundcolor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQe3X.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with

```
HasUnevenRows = "true"
```

for "Disable selection" you can follow these

[Disabling selection](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Disabling_Selection)

```
SelectionDemoList.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
};
```

Note that on Windows Phone, some cells, including SwitchCell don't update their visual state in response to selection.

To reduce the ListView's height you can use a Grid. This is a sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="TestRelativeLayout.MyPage2">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Entry Placeholder="MyEntry" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2"/>
                    <Image Source="icon.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row = "0" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <Grid VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ListView x:Name="ListGroups" 
                    Grid.Row = "0"
                    Grid.Column = "0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding myList}" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    BackgroundColor = "Red">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Aqua" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row = "1" Grid.Column = "0" >
                    <Label Text="If you feel you're missing"
                        FontSize="15"
                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        TextColor="Black" />
                    <Label Text="a group or two, please contact"
                        FontSize="15"
                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        TextColor="Black" />
                    <Label Text="your manager"
                        FontSize="15"
                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        TextColor="Black" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

you have this (on Emulator / Android)

[image: Sample]

Comment: it actually worked perfectly thank you , do you have any solution for disable selection ? @Alessandro Caliaro

Comment: ListView_OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as ListView).SelectedItem = null;
        }

Comment: but now i have a unused space under the list , How i delete this , it wont go @Alessandro Caliaro

Comment: I think you can play with "VerticalOptions". Something like "Start"... without "Expand"

Comment: in the listview you mean @AlessandroCaliaro

Comment: i have addd an image in my post please see and tell me what your approach would be @AlessandroCaliaro

Comment: can you set a background color for listview so we can understand where it finishes?

Comment: i added a color and a pic please see  @AlessandroCaliaro

Comment: the xaml is the one you have post? or you have used verticaloptin?

Comment: i have edited and show thewhole xmal of my stacklayout , i tried playing with vertical option and didnt work  @AlessandroCaliaro

Comment: Can you post a image how you would like to have your layout? ListView occupy all the space available... if you want it occupy some space, you can use a Grid...

Comment: i tried a grid and it made the same result , i just want the unused space under list to vanish @AlessandroCaliaro  , i want my layout to be without from empty spaces  , so the list then directly the labels